# dynamic custom value paypal button

Tags: paypal

is possible to send combination of encrypted and decrypted input in paypal button?

sample

```
                                <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="" id="ctm_first_name">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="" id="ctm_last_name">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="" id="ctm_address_street">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="address2" value="" id="ctm_address_street_two">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="city" value="" id="ctm_address_city">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="state" value="" id="ctm_address_state">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="" id="ctm_address_zip">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="" id="ctm_payer_email">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="" id="ctm_val">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7
```

-----END PKCS7-----
                                        ">

i have a dynamic data that i im populating using javascript..im afraid if its encrypted i cant call the input name or id ..so my javascript population code wont work

so can i pass input decrypt t and encrypt at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to decide the button type: hosted/encrypted and then use one type of button only.

You can use plaintext button as well but hosted button works best.

Example of plain text

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/html_example_buy_now/